# How to set 2 columns left in admin form in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, layout, ui-form

I have created layout with ui component form. But now I want to add tab in admin layout.

I already set `layout="2columns-left"` in layout but it's showing only my one ui compnent form.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="editor"/>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <uiComponent name="my_ui_form"/>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceContainer name="left">
           .....
           .....
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

How to set 2columns left in Admin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

we must use `admin-2columns-left` for admin layout

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
.....
.....    
</page>
```

Comment: but this won't do 2 columns in the form, only add 2 columns in the page that contain the form...